# Orthogonal diagonalization without eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

I stumbled onto a method for orthogonally diagonalizing a symmetric matrix with real entries and I was wondering what advantages (if any at all) it has over the eigenvector method.

It hinges on the fact that every symmetric matrix may be viewed as a dot product on some vector space. The idea is to use the Gram-Schmidt process to get zeros in every entry that is not on the diagonal.

What is this method called? What are its practical applications? (besides computing powers of matrices)
[description of the method here since I cannot embed pictures directly into the post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBiFI.jpg)

Comment: Here you find a diagonal matrix that is [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) to the original matrix $A$. Note that a symmetric matrix can always be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix, which means that $A$ is both similar and congruent to the diagonal matrix made of eigenvalues. Advantage over the eigendecomposition: finitely many steps. Major drawback: one is usually more interested in [similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity).

Comment: Similarity is equivalent to a change of basis, so the eigenvalues do not depend on the basis. The eigenvectors do, however. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2795340/do-eigenvalues-depend-on-the-choice-of-basis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a decomposition similar to the Cholesky called the $LDL$ decomposition

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import ldl

A = np.array([[3,-1,0],[-1,2,-1],[0,-1,3]])
A

array([[ 3, -1,  0],
       [-1,  2, -1],
       [ 0, -1,  3]])

lu, d, perm = ldl(A, lower =0)

lu

array([[ 1.        , -0.6       ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  1.        , -0.33333333],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])

d


array([[2.4       , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 1.66666667, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 3.        ]]
```

Note that $2.4 = \frac{12}{5}$ and $1.\overline{666} = \frac{5}{3}$